# Erro no fragment

Tags: android-fragment, fragment

Estou tentando fazer um calendário para aniversários, porém no *fragment* onde coloquei o calendário está dando um erro que não sei como corrigir.

**Error**

```
06-02 01:17:33.346 15106-15106/com.example.educador.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.educador.myapplication, PID: 15106
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView.setUseThreeLetterAbbreviation(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.educador.myapplication.Aniversarios.onCreateView(Aniversarios.java:49)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**Código do *Fragment***:

```
public class Aniversarios extends Fragment {

    CompactCalendarView compactCalendar;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM- yyyy", Locale.getDefault());


    public Aniversarios() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_aniversarios);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setTitle(null);

        compactCalendar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.compactcalendar_view);
        compactCalendar.setUseThreeLetterAbbreviation(true);

        //Set an event for Teachers' Professional Day 2016 which is 21st of October

        Event ev1 = new Event(Color.RED, 1477040400000L, "Teachers' Professional Day");
        compactCalendar.addEvent(ev1);

        compactCalendar.setListener(new CompactCalendarView.CompactCalendarViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDayClick(Date dateClicked) {
                Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

                if (dateClicked.toString().compareTo("Fri Oct 21 00:00:00 AST 2016") == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Teachers' Professional Day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No Events Planned for that day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onMonthScroll(Date firstDayOfNewMonth) {
                actionBar.setTitle(dateFormatMonth.format(firstDayOfNewMonth));
            }

        });



        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aniversarios, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: O problema provavelmente está em *Main2Activity.java*, linha *153*. Você está tentando utilizar o método `isDrawerOpen` de um elemento nulo.

Comment: o que tem na proximo da linha 153 no _Main2Activity.java_     
`@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }`

Comment: `findViewById` está retornando `null` pois o elemento `R.id.drawer_layout` não existe no *layout (XML)*.

Comment: Desculpe vou reeditar o erro era outro tinha feito edição e n tinha colocado novamente...

Comment: A mesma coisa. O trecho `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.compactcalendar_view)` não está retornando um objeto (provavelmente não existe no *XML*). Isso faz que variável `compactCalendar` receba um valor `null` e ao tentar acessar um método (`setUseThreeLetterAbbreviation`, por exemplo) ocorre o erro `(...) on a null object reference`

Comment: Se você adicionar o código `System.out.println( compactCalendar )`, verá que o resultado, no *logcat*, será `null`.

Comment: o _XML_ existe sim..


`<com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/compactcalendar_view"
...
/>`

Comment: o bizarro q quando coloco executa apesar de não rodar perfeitamente mas roda 99%>>
`public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_aniversarios);`

Comment: Esse *XML* dentro do *layout* principal?

Comment: está dentro do _layout_ do fragment onde quero q apareça

Comment: Então não faz sentido usar `getActivity().findViewById()`. https://hastebin.com/litegokati.java

Comment: qual sugestão ? o q usar ?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr
realmente aconteceu como vc disse...
`06-02 02:43:31.877 18996-18996/com.example.educador.myapplication I/System.out: null`

Comment: codigo _xml_  https://hastebin.com/dalowonezo.xml

Comment: Descobri!!!!!!!

Comment: Solução implementada >> https://hastebin.com/rehaveveji.java

Comment: encontrei a solução aqui>>>
http://helpdev.com.br/2017/11/30/android-como-pegar-uma-view-da-activity-dentro-de-um-fragment-getactivity-findviewbyid-returns-null-called-from-fragment-onactivitycreated/

Comment: Obrigado @ValdeirPsr pela moral ae me ajudou mt ^^